# Finding a Concrete Implementation of a Generic Interface in Ninject

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have a generic interface with specific implementations as follows:

```
public class Animal { }
public class Horse : Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }

public interface Vet<in T> where T : Animal
{
    void Heal(T animal);
}

public class HorseVet : Vet<Horse>
{
    public void Heal(Horse animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Healing a horse");
    }
}

public class DogVet : Vet<Dog>
{
    public void Heal(Dog animal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Healing a dog");
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to create an instance of the appropriate concrete implementation of `Vet<T>` given an `Animal` at runtime, as follows:

```
StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<Vet<Horse>>().To<HorseVet>();
kernel.Bind<Vet<Dog>>().To<DogVet>();

var animals = new Animal[] { new Horse(), new Dog() };

foreach (Animal animal in animals)
{
    // how do I get the right Vet<T> type here so I can call Heal(animal)?
}
```

My question is, how can I achieve the above so the correct implementation is retrieved, or do I need to refactor to a different way of organising my classes?

I've looked at the Ninject Factory Extension but that also doesn't seem to offer what I'm looking for.

If I wasn't using an IoC container, I'd do something like:

```
public Vet<Animal> Create(Animal animal)
{
    if (animal is Horse)
    {
        return new HorseVet();
    }
    else if ...
}
```

Comment: `return new Vet<Horse>` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
foreach (Animal animal in animals)
{
    Type vetType = typeof(Vet<>).MakeGenericType(animal.GetType());
    object vet = kernel.Get(vetType);
}
```

But the question now becomes how do you want to use this type? You might be tempted to do something like this:

```
var vet = (Vet<Animal>)kernel.Get(vetType);
vet.Heal(animal);
```

But this doesn't work, because instances of `Vet<Dog>` and `Vet<Horse>` can't be cast to `Vet<Animal>`, because this would require `Vet<T>` to be defined with an `out` keyword as in `Vet<out Animal>`. But this of course wouldn't work, because `Vet<T>` has an input parameter of type `Animal`.

So to solve this you either need a second non-generic `Vet` interface, or you need to either use reflection or dynamic typing. Using the non-generic interface might look like this:

```
public interface Vet {
    void Heal(Animal animal);
}

public interface Vet<T> : Vet where T : Animal {
    void Heal(T animal);
}

// Usage
var vet = (Vet)kernel.Get(vetType);
vet.Heal(animal);
```

Problem however is that this pollutes the implementations, because they suddenly need to implement a second method.

Another option is to use dynamic typing or reflection:

```
dynamic vet = kernel.Get(vetType);
vet.Heal((dynamic)animal);
```

Downside of course is that you would lose compile-time support, but if these two lines of code are the only lines in the application that call the vet like that, I would say it is fine. You can easily add a unit test that checks this code.

Do note btw that the `in` keyword on `Vet<in T>` is probably useless, unless you have vet implementations on both `Dog` and `GoldenRetriever` and want to be able to apply a `GoldenRetriever` to a `Vet<Dog>`.

Comment: Small correction: you have a missing closing parenthesis of `MakeGenericType`.

Comment: @Steven Yep, I'd worked that out, but that doesn't really help in this situation, because I now need to call the `Heal` method on that object and I can't because it's just type `object`.

Comment: One already needs to use reflection to define the closed-generic `Vet` type. So i'd suggest to instead use reflection to close a generic method `Handle<TAnmial>`. This method can then do all the operations on the closed generic type.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit: I advice the opposite, because calling the `Heal` method using reflection would cause any exception to be wrapped in a `InvocationException` while this will not happen when calling methods using dynamic typing.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit: This might not always be an issue, but it usually is quite annoying behavior in the scenarios where I usually use dynamics (I use dynamics to do dispatching as described [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92). In those cases I usually want to handle specific exceptions up the callstack, and the wrapping of the `InvocationException` makes this really ugly. But I do agree with you, the use of the reflection API is much more expressive than dynamics and a much better warning sign (just like the use of `unsafe` is).

Comment: @Steven i usually fix that by `catch (TargetInvocationException tex)` which does `ExceptionDispatchInfo.capture(tex.InnerException).Throw()`. (This is done at the same place where i use the generics and invoke the method. So all the generics and invocation stuff is wrapped in one place)

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit: Wow, that's really cool. I learned something new today. It only adds one extra line in the stack trace, but completely removes the outer exception without losing the stack trace. Unfortunately this only works under .NET 4.5 and up. No PCL :-(.

Comment: For older .net versions the following hack works: https://github.com/bbvcommon/bbv.Common/blob/344d1dfe61d3e3c3c9240eb9cb6c27a2148103dc/source/bbv.Common/ExceptionExtensionMethods.cs#L34 we've been using it for years before `ExceptionDispatchInfo` became available... Don't know if it works for all PCL targets though.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit: Won't work in PCL, or at least for me PCL is aquivilent of 'running in a sandbox', but you skip the operation (with `#if SILVERLIGHT`) when running in a sandbox.